# Por que no me lee el archivo de css con el Flaks

Tags: html, python, flask

Tengo un archivo de css en la carpeta de static, dentro de otra carpeta llamada css, pero al momento de hacer la llamada dentro del código no me aparece nada, que hago al respecto o me falta algo en el código

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ademas en la consola me aparece este tipo de error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es lo que tengo en el codigo y la parte que esta dentro del código y esta ubicado dentro del `<head>`

```
(<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/main.css') }}">)
```

Answer (score 0):

Aunque no muestras la estructura de la app al completo, en principio el problema es que tu ruta a `static` no es correcta, tienes la carpeta dentro de `templates`, cuando debería estar fuera, al mismo nivel, si quieres que la ruta sea resuelta de forma correcta con la configuración por defecto.

Si aún así, quieres que `static` esté dentro de `templates`, sin entrar en la lógica de ésto, debes indicarle a Flask dónde está la carpeta de forma explícita:

```
app = Flask(__name__, ,static_folder='./templates/static')
```